# Do I need to release the DC when the hwnd is NULL?

Tags: winapi, release, dc

I'm using `HDC dc = GetDC(null);` to get the DC from desktop but it isn't clear to me if I must release it with a `ReleaseDC()` call. If so, how should I do that? `ReleaseDC(NULL, dc)`?

Comment: What the answer in the linked post doesn't say: Yes, you call `ReleaseDC` with a `NULL` `HWND`. So `ReleaseDC(NULL, dc)` is correct.

Comment: @dialer Thanks! I was going to ask that because the linked post isn't an exact duplicate, for me